# Poor Image Quality/Best way to save

Tags: adobe-photoshop, resolution

please i have been designing on photoshop for a while my designs looks good but the quality is really bad although i use the usual 300/72 px, the images and texts looks blurry, i dont even understand the best way to save anymore cause i've tried different methods but its still the same, this is making my work look armature pleaaase help

Comment: What is "the usual 300/72 px"? There are a number of previous questions here relating to what resolution to work at, how to export etc. but I'm not sure exactly what you're asking. Please take a minute to read through the [help] and specifically [how to ask](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) to see how the site works.

Comment: This is fairly impossible to answer without understanding final *output* goals and starting sources. Start with a small 72ppi image and **nothing** you do to it, other than making it smaller,  will "improve' it's appearance.

Answer (score 1):

> designing on photoshop

Designing what? Brochures, Logos, banners for web?

> i use the usual 300/72 px

What is that? Totally forget about the 72ppi.

300 ppi does not say anything. If you have a tiny little image of 50x50 px, asigning 300 ppi won't save the day.

Work on a big file, proportionally to the output.

Let us say a 3000x2000 image. A 6000x4000 px one is better.

> the best way to save anymore

Save your work as PSD. The native image format of photoshop.

> this is making my work look armature

Ok Back to question one.

Designing what? Photoshop is NOT the best place to design some things. Brochures, logos, posters etc need to be done in Ilustrator, Corel, Indesign or Scribus.

Photoshop needs to be used to apply effects to raster images, photo manipulation, etc, on a **good resolution image**.

You are simply using the wrong tool or the wrong file size.

Answer (score -2):

In Photoshop, your best bet is to go to File>Export>Export As, then choose your file/image type and size. Alternatively, you can use the "Save For Web" option if your image is for a screen/the web, or export your image as a PDF for printing.

Remember, when you're setting up your PSD, make sure to use 300 dpi for images used in print mediums, or at least 72 dpi for images viewed on screens/the web. Try to set up your PSD to be the size you will need for your final product, as scaling your rasterized image can cause the image  quality to take a hit.

Comment: The 72 dpi myth? in 2016? http://www.photoshopessentials.com/essentials/the-72-ppi-web-resolution-myth/